# R to latex: sanitize both % and \latexfunction at the same time

Tags: r, latex

After some R computations I obtained a matrix that looks like that:

```
matrix <- cbind(c(00,01,02),c("some text","random stuff","special characters'"), c("0.12%","\\cellcolor{red!25}3.67%","1.61%"))
```

I am trying to export it to latex as follow:

```
file.name  <-  "file.name"
file.caption  <- "file.caption"
print(xtable(matrix, align = c("l","r","r","r"),
                              label = paste("tab:", file.name, sep = "", collapse = NULL),
                              caption = file.caption),
      type = "latex",
      size="\\normalsize",
      caption.placement = "top",
      # file = paste("graphs/", file.name, ".tex", sep = "", collapse = NULL),
      floating = FALSE,
      tabular.environment = "longtable",
      sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
```

If I do not `sanitize` it, the pdf displays "\cellcolor{red!25}" (and obviously, I would prefer to have the cell colored). If I `sanitize` I can not typset the file.tex because of the "%".
I tried `sanitize.text.function = function(x) x` and `sanitize.text.function = identity`... without success.
Any idea?

Comment: can you escape them `0.12\\%`

Comment: @user20650 What a wonderful idea! Problem solved!